# Yii: Where does $this->menu filled with values?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

Gii created a CRUD menu called **operations**. If you go to column2.php you will see this code.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
        'items'=>$this->menu,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
```

For some reason I want to edit above menu. I wonder where does $this->menu is filled with values which is defined in **components/controller.php**. I looked at every controller's code but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The menu is filled in view file (create.php, update.php, view.php, etc)

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason I want to edit above menu

What exactly you wanna do? If you want to change the way it's behave, you should try the CMenu.php file, located at `/yii/framework/zii/widgets/`